# Mining on testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets

I am very new to Ethereum. I have setup two machines, a Windows 10 machine and a Ubuntu 17 Server in the Cloud. Both of these nodes are synced to the testnet.

But when I start mining on these to machines using `miner.start(2)`, I am not getting any ethers on the Ubuntu machine.

Below is the log from the Ubuntu machine;

```
INFO [06-29|10:00:22] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=3 mgas=0.295 elapsed=19.224ms  mgasps=15.330 number=1207253 hash=7777de…72e5ce
INFO [06-29|10:00:22] Commit new mining work                   number=1207254 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=1.124ms
INFO [06-29|10:01:14] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=11.038ms  mgasps=0.000  number=1207254 hash=14ed4a…c924ab
INFO [06-29|10:01:14] Commit new mining work                   number=1207255 txs=6 uncles=0 elapsed=8.730ms
INFO [06-29|10:01:28] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=6 mgas=0.195 elapsed=14.005ms  mgasps=13.895 number=1207255 hash=433ba1…e37dbf
INFO [06-29|10:01:28] Commit new mining work                   number=1207256 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.002ms
```

Please advise on what am I missing here.

Comment: Which testnet are you on? (Kovan, Ropsten, or Rinkeby)

Comment: @TjadenHess Log says `ChainID: 3`, so I am on `Ropsten`?

Comment: Could just be that you don't have enough hash power to get ETH. What's your hashrate?

Comment: @TjadenHess it is 28932

Comment: How long have you been mining? My calculation says it should take about 7 hours on average for you to find a block

Comment: @TjadenHess around 5 hours. Do I have any other options for getting some ethers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply that despite being a testnet, there is about .05GH/s of hashing power currently on Ropsten which can make it impractical for small computers to mine their own ETH.

You can get around this issue in a couple ways:

1. Use a faucet. A few can be found on google, and will give you a few ETH for free.
2. Use the [Kovan](https://kovan-testnet.github.io/website/) testnet. This requires you to use the parity client, but it does not use proof of work and instead has a semi-centralized system for distributing test ETH.